# opencart 2.0.1.2 redirecting to /app on openshift

Tags: php, opencart, openshift, cname

```
Host: openshift
opencart  2.0.1.2 
Points To: myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com
domain name: www.example.com
When I access www.example.com I only get:
```

Not Found

The requested URL https://www.example.com/app was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at www.example.com Port 443

I have saved alias Name successfully in openshift and provided the cname properly in domain hosting, I have changed the config.php file with the same domain name (www.example.com)

Do anyone have any idea why I am unable to access my application on www.xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added both the naked domain (example.com) and the cname (www.example.com) as aliases for your application on OpenShift.